# STLloader/THREE.js error: "Uncaught RangeError: offset is outside the bounds of the DataView"

Tags: javascript, node.js, three.js, stl-format

I want to code a little viewer of stl files in javascript so for this a use the library three.js with the module STLLoader, for this viewer i use a system of upload make with an API in node.js (I send files by using fetch request and on backside formidable save files ) and for the viwer the page make a request on a adress with fetch and get the stl file content, now for load stl data I use this code :

```
var contents = stl_name;

var geometry = new THREE.STLLoader().parse( contents );
geometry.sourceType = "stl";

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
mesh.rotation.x = 5;
mesh.rotation.z = .25;
scene.add( mesh );
```

but it's return an error (i have this error just with stl binary files, the ASCII stl files works correctly) : "Uncaught RangeError: offset is outside the bounds of the DataView",
I don't how sold it, thank you in advance.

An exemple of test files : [test.stl](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19RUrcigeYrOzBLoRD_CiepCytq4IJ1qZ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Do you mind sharing one of your binary STL files in this thread?

Comment: I have edit the original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem by adding node.js library in my API (stl) convert binary stl to ASCII stl. [link to the library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stl)

Answer (score 0):

I can succesfully import the asset into the [three.js editor](https://threejs.org/editor/) via drag'n'drop. So it seems there is a problem in your app OR you are not using the latest version of `three.js`.

In any event, try to use a [similar code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/editor/js/Loader.js#L551-L583) like in the editor. It is essentially this:

```js
const reader = new FileReader();

reader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {

    const contents = event.target.result;

    const geometry = new THREE.STLLoader().parse( contents );
    const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial();

    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    mesh.name = filename;

    scene.add( mesh );

}, false );

reader.readAsArrayBuffer( file );
```